# PyYAML - Saving data to .yaml files

Tags: python, yaml

So I've picked up PyYAML over the past few days but I feel like some of the documentation is vague or I'm misinterpreting it. Here is a function for *writing* data to a .yaml which can write the values to each element I have in the list:

```
def writeSave(filename, **kwargs):
    with open(filename, 'r') as yamlFile:
        yamlDict = yaml.load(yamlFile)
        if not yamlDict: yamlDict = {}

    with open(filename, 'w') as write:
        z = yamlDict.copy()
        z.update(kwargs)
        yaml.dump(z, write)
```

Which will then overwrite the values below when called:

```
saveData:
        {mission_state: 7, playername: 'steve'}
```

Using this function seems simple:

```
writeSave('../path/savedata.yaml', mission_state=2)
```

Which will then change the `mission_state` in the list.

I don't know if I've done this smoothly or if there is a better practice to performing these kind of functions. If there are, it'd be nice to have some kind of pointers.

Is there a way to make this more readable? Maybe more readable vars or more commenting?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- First, Python has an official style-guide, [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), which you should follow. It recommends using `lower_case` for functions and variables.
- I would also rename your function, since `write_save` does not say what this function is doing. I think `overwrite_setting` or `update_value` or something similar would be better.
- You might want to add a check if any keyword arguments are passed to the function. Either raise an exception (a simple `AssertionError` might be enough), or at least don't waste time reading the file and writing the same content back.
- While `open` opens a file in read-mode by default, here I think it is actually fine to open it once explicitly with `'r'` and then with `'w'`.
- Your `z = yamDict.copy()` should be completely unnecessary. Mutating the original dictionary does not do any harm. The updating does not need to be within the `with` block either.
- Finally, you could use `or` for the check of an empty dictionary.

With all of the above changes, your code would become:

```
import yaml

def update_value(filename, **kwargs):
    assert kwargs
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        yaml_dict = yaml.load(f) or {}
    yaml_dict.update(kwargs)
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        yaml.dump(yaml_dict, f)
```

---

If you have only one thread, you could skip the reading of the config everytime you want to change a value and instead keep the dictionary in memory (after having it read once at the beginning). You will still want the write to save state, though. For this you might want to have a `Config` class, derived from `dict`:

```
import os

class Config(dict):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename
        if os.path.isfile(filename):
            with open(filename) as f:
                # use super here to avoid unnecessary write
                super(Config, self).update(yaml.load(f) or {})

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        super(Config, self).__setitem__(key, value)
        with open(self.filename, "w") as f:
            yaml.dump(self, f)

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        super(Config, self).__delitem__(key)
        with open(self.filename, "w") as f:
            yaml.dump(self, f)

    def update(self, kwargs):
        super(Config, self).update(kwargs)
        with open(self.filename, "w") as f:
            yaml.dump(self, f)
```

You might want to define a decorator to add the dumping part to the methods:

```
import functools

def dumps(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ret = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
        with open(self.filename, "w") as f:
            yaml.dump(self, f)
        return ret
    return wrapper

class Config(dict):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename
        if os.path.isfile(filename):
            with open(filename) as f:
                # use super here to avoid unnecessary write
                super(Config, self).update(yaml.load(f) or {})

    __setitem__ = dumps(dict.__setitem__)
    __delitem__ = dumps(dict.__delitem__)
    update = dumps(dict.update)
```

You can use this class like a `dict`, but every change to the dictionary is also dumped to the yaml file. The file is only read once (when the config is initialized), so changes to the file will only be visible when the script is re-started.

```
cfg = Config("test.yaml")
print(cfg)
cfg['a'] = 3
print(cfg)
cfg.update({"b": 4})
cfg.update(c=5)
del cfg['a']
print(cfg)
```

Comment: Amazing! Really insightful and well explained. I specifically enjoyed the derived dict class since that can really simplify things for me.

Comment: @Anthon I would prefer it if the answer stayed as it is. In your answer you can always refer to my answer as a baseline and improve upon it (all user content here is licensed as CC-BY-SA 3.0 with attribution, so just saying it and linking to my answer is sufficient). Note that answers here do not have to fully "answer" the "question" (I.e. review the code in all aspects). Partial answers are perfectly fine, so no need to reiterate for example the style issues I pointed out.

Answer (score 8):

The answer by @Graipher addresses many of the issues with your code very well, and I am not going to repeat those here. This answer only addresses one potential **safety issue** existing in your original code (and not addressed in @Graipher's answer), and has a few additional observations resulting from the shortcomings of PyYAML.

#### Safety issue

The use of PyYAML's `yaml.load()` is documented to be potentially unsafe. Uncontrolled YAML input can lead to a wiped harddrive or worse. There briefly existed a version of PyYAML in the summer of 2018 addressing this, but that version was retracted because of problems, which still have not been solved (at least not within six months).

There is seldom, if ever, need to use `yaml.load()`, instead **always** use `yaml.safe_load()`. If you happen to have tags in your YAML, just register the constructors for them on `yaml.SafeLoader` instead of the (default) unsafe `Loader`.

#### Performance

YAML loaders/dumpers are slow, especially compared to loader/dumpers for much simpler formats such as JSON. You should consider postponing the dumping of changes from memory to file, if the config file is not used by any other program (i.e. only preserves configuration for the current program).

@Graipher's code for the `Config` class can be adapted to optionally postpone the dump to the config file:

```
class Config(dict):
    def __init__(self, filename, auto_dump=True):
        self.filename = filename
        self.auto_dump = auto_dump
        self.changed = False
        if os.path.isfile(filename):
            with open(filename) as f:
                # use super here to avoid unnecessary write
                super(Config, self).update(yaml.load(f) or {})

    def dump(self, force=False):
        if not self.changed and not force:
            return
        with open(self.filename, "w") as f:
            yaml.safe_dump(self, f)
        self.changed = False

    def updated(self):
        if self.auto_dump:
            self.dump(force=True)
        else:
            self.changed = True

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        super(Config, self).__setitem__(key, value)
        self.updated()

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        super(Config, self).__delitem__(key)
        self.updated()

    def update(self, kwargs):
        super(Config, self).update(kwargs)
        self.updated()
```

You could additionally make the object dump to file if it goes out of scope, but I  would just call `cfg.dump()` explicitly.

#### YAML 1.2 vs 1.1 and other PyYAML issues

The YAML standard was updated in 2009 to version 1.2, but PyYAML still only supports YAML 1.1. This can lead to several surprises, including:

- The scalars `Off`, `On`, `Yes` and `No` are (still) loaded as booleans by PyYAML (as well as all-caps and all-lowercase versions of these strings)
- Scalars with a leading zero are considered octal if all of the other characters are in the `[0-7]` range (instead of requiring a leading `0o` as specified in YAML 1.2).
- Scalars that have the form of a sexagesimal are loaded by PyYAML as integers instead of a string

You should also be aware that your configuration file will lose any comments, special anchor names on mappings and sequences, (superfluous) quotes around scalars, and that cannot preserve specific style (flow/block) on nodes (enforcing one of three styles "globally") and that any non-ASCII input might get dumped as escape sequences.

If you want to address any or all of those problems with PyYAML, you should consider using `ruamel.yaml` (disclaimer I am the author of that package). You could e.g. replace the `__init__` and `dump` methods of the updated version of class `Config` with:

```
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

class Config(dict):
    def __init__(self, filename, auto_dump=True):
        self.filename = filename
        self.auto_dump = auto_dump
        self.changed = False
        self.yaml = YAML()
        self.yaml.preserve_quotes = True
        # uncomment and adapt to your specific indentation
        # self.yaml.indent(mapping=4, sequence=4, offset=2)
        if os.path.isfile(filename):
            with open(filename) as f:
                # use super here to avoid unnecessary write
                super(Config, self).update(self.yaml.load(f) or {})

    def dump(self, force=False):
        if not self.changed and not force:
            return
        with open(self.filename, "w") as f:
            # cast as you don't want to dump Config's attributes
            self.yaml.dump(dict(self), f)
        self.changed = False

    # following methods unchanged from PyYAML example
    def updated(self):
        if self.auto_dump:
            self.dump(force=True)
        else:
            self.changed = True

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        super(Config, self).__setitem__(key, value)
        self.updated()

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        super(Config, self).__delitem__(key)
        self.updated()

    def update(self, kwargs):
        super(Config, self).update(kwargs)
        self.updated()
```

Comment: the 2nd last line in dump() is `yaml.dump(self, f)`, however `yaml` is undefined. Also it would be helpful for me to see the entire class in one place. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. That should of course be `self.yaml`

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer does not point on how to update nested dictionary. I have tried to come up with a solution to handle it. For `Graiper`'s solutions related to nested `dict`, I was not able to do something as follows: `cfg.update({a:{"b": 4}})`, which cause an error:

`yaml.constructor.ConstructorError: could not determine a constructor for the tag 'tag:yaml.org,2002:python/object/new:__main__.Config'`

---

Following solution handles nested dictionary, such as: `data[out-key][in-key]=new-value`.

- `Yaml("test.yaml").data` points to the loaded yaml object.
- After updating `Yaml("test.yaml").data` object `Yaml("test.yaml").dump()` is required to save the updated `yaml` object.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import yaml


class Yaml(dict):
    def __init__(self, fname, auto_dump=True):
        self.fname = fname
        if os.path.isfile(fname):
            with open(fname) as f:
                self.data = yaml.safe_load(f)
        else:
            self.data:dict = {}

    def update(self, key, value):
        """Update given key's value."""
        self.data[key] = value
        self.dump()

    def dump(self):
        """Save yaml object with its updated version."""
        with open(self.fname, "w") as f:
            yaml.safe_dump(self.data, f, default_flow_style=False)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    y = Yaml("test.yaml")
    y.data["a"]["b"] = 10
    y.update("b", 101)
    y.dump()
```

---

`test.yaml`:

```yaml
a:
  b: 1
b: 1
```

Comment: You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please [edit] to show what aspects of the question code prompted you to write this version, and in what ways it's an improvement over the original.  It may be worth (re-)reading [answer].